# Azure App Service Canary Deployment through Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-app-service-plans, canary-deployment

We use Azure Devops process to do a deploy to our staging slot and then we do a straight swap between staging and production.

We note that through the portal interface we can direct a percent of the traffic to staging, is there a method to do this through Azure Devops/CD process so that we direct a percent of traffic to a specific slot and then gradually increase, essentially a canary deployment method via the pipeline using Azure Web App Slots?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) it looks that is possible:

[image: Deployments slots]

> Next to the Azure portal, you can also use the [az webapp traffic-routing set command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/traffic-routing#az-webapp-traffic-routing-set) in the Azure CLI to set the routing
>   percentages from CI/CD tools like DevOps pipelines or other automation
>   systems.

you can use this command to increase traffic:

```bsh
az webapp traffic-routing set --distribution staging=50 --name MyWebApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

and with `Start-Sleep -Seconds 10` you can gradually increase percentage.

Comment: Ahhh this is awesome thank you so much, will test this out and see how it goes, much appreciated